# Prove the following: 2

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

how to prove the following:

> In Exercises $67$-$74$, prove the given property.
>   $\qquad67.\quad |ab|=|a||b|$
>   $\qquad68.\quad |a-b|=|b-a|$ [Hint: Use Exercise $67$ and the fact that
>   $\qquad\qquad\,(a-b)=(-1)(b-a)$.]
>   $\qquad69.\quad \left|\dfrac{a}b\right|=\dfrac{|a|}{|b|}, b\ne 0$
>   $\qquad70.\quad |a|=\sqrt{a^2}$
>   $\qquad71.\quad \left|a^n\right|=|a|^n, n=1,2,3\ldots$
>   $\qquad72.\quad -|a|\le a\le|a|$
>   $\qquad73.\quad |a|\le k$ if and only if $-k\le a\le k$, $k\geq 0$.
>   $\qquad74.\quad k\le|a|$ if and only if $k\le a$ or $a\le -k$, $k\ge 0$.

If I let $x,y\in R$ and prove by exhaustion do I do this by considering when $x\geq 0,y\geq 0$ then $|ab|=|a||b|$ and when $x<0,y<0$ then $|ab|=|−a||−b|=|a||b|$.
by this definition shall i prove all the problems

Comment: How does one prove the number 2?

Comment: The cases "both x,y greater than zero" and "both x,y less than zero" do not exhaust all cases. What definition? I'm not sure that the first problem will help prove all the problems, but it might be useful on some...

Comment: The thing you linked isn't "a proof," it's a list of 8 exercises from a text. Are we working on the first one only?

Comment: The second exercise is a not-necessarily-true statement--Is that supposed to be $|a-b| = |b-a|$?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with differential geometry?

Answer (score 4):

Be consistent with your use of variables:

E.g., you write:

> "If I let $x,y\in R$ and prove by exhaustion do I do this by considering when $x\geq 0,y\geq 0$ then $|ab|=|a||b|$ and when $x<0,y<0$ then $|ab|=|−a||−b|=|a||b|$.

Use either strictly $x, y$, or $a, b$.

Certainly, use the definition of the absolute value of real numbers, and you can certainly prove each of the properties by exhaustion: we call that a "proof by cases".  But caution, we we are using $a, b \in \mathbb R$, then yes, we need to consider each property $(67 - 69)$ given the cases:

- $a \gt 0, b\gt 0$ (save for having $b > 0$ in $(69)$.
- $a \lt 0, b\lt 0$.

But we also need to consider what happens when

- $a \gt 0, b \lt 0$ or $a \lt 0, b > 0$
- $a = 0,$ and/or $b = 0$

For the properties with one variable, choose $a \in \mathbb R$ and consider the cases $a > 0, a = 0, a < 0$. And in $73-74$, you need to consider different cases for the value of $k$ in order to prove each statement.

Comment: Long to write up! +1